# How to validate only alphnumarics and only digits using validation plugin of jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi could anyone please explain me about how to validate the only alphanumerics,digits and how to avoid the special characters using jquery validate plugin.
Ex: i have filed like designation that has to take only alphabets and should not take special char.And How to validate radio buttons. except this normal validation is working fine.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.validator.addMethod("loginRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-\s]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");
    $('#employee_table').validate({
        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true

            },
            lastname: {
                minlength: 1,
                required: true
            },
            generateemployeeID: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            sourceofhire: {
                required: true
            },
            otheremail: {
                email: true,
                minlength: 10

            },
            agree: "required"

        },
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element
                    .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Simply include [the additional-methods.js file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js) for the `alphanumeric` rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can validate...

- only digits with [`digits`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/).
- decimal numbers with [`number`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/number-method/).
- only alphanumeric characters with [`alphanumeric`](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js). Thanks to @Sparky.

You can validate a checkbox or radiobutton with `required` rule.

Comment: where should I need to add In my above code and how to call that function.Could u please expline me

Comment: Have you read the links I posted? I think you can add your custom function in the same file at the top.

Comment: i have updated my question and added this custom method but I am not getting where to add the messages to display.

Comment: Have you read this page? http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/. All you need to know is in this page: error class, error element, error placement, messages...

Comment: really I read all the document but I am not understating that how to display the messages.

Comment: Um, the `alphanumeric` rule is already part of [the plugin's additional-methods.js file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js). So there is no need to create custom methods in this case.